# When developing query modules for Memgraph in Python how to get type completion?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'd like to have type completion when developing query modules for Memgraph in Python. Is it possible to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install `mgp`. This is PyPi package used for type hinting when creating query modules. It can bee installed using `pip install mgp`. The package can also be found at https://pypi.org/project/mgp/.